# MemberTimeToLive paramater, does it correct work?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.0

Good afternoon, I have a question about the powershell functionality that appeared in Windows Server 2016.

The `-MemberTimeToLive` parameter on the `Add-ADGroupMember` cmdlet, how does it work?

The problem is this:

I add to the group where 5-10 people (test group) the user Enrike for 1 day.
Then using

```
Get-ADGroup -Identity "test group" -property member -ShowMemberTimeToLive | Select-Object -ExpandProperty member
```

I can see that Enrike is in the group and the specified time after which he will be removed from it.
But if I add a user to a group with more than 3000 people, this command does not display the time `<TTL =>`, although the restrictions are still in effect and the user will be deleted after the specified time.

I am writing a utility for myself where I can conveniently see in which group how much time is left to whom, but this problem haunts me and I cannot watch the remaining time in large groups.

Answer (score -1):

Try with these powershell commands

```
1)  Get-ADGroup [-AuthType <ADAuthType>][-Credential <PSCredential>]
   -Filter <String> [-Properties <String[]>][-ResultPageSize <Int32>]
   [-ResultSetSize <Int32>][-SearchBase <String>][-SearchScope <ADSearchScope>]
   [-Server <String>][-ShowMemberTimeToLive][<CommonParameters>]

2)Get-ADGroup
   [-AuthType <ADAuthType>][-Credential <PSCredential>][-Identity] <ADGroup>
   [-Partition <String>][-Properties <String[]>][-Server <String>]
   [-ShowMemberTimeToLive][<CommonParameters>]

3) Get-ADGroup[-AuthType <ADAuthType>]-  [-Credential <PSCredential>]
   -LDAPFilter <String>[-Properties <String[]>][-ResultPageSize <Int32>]
   [-ResultSetSize <Int32>] [-SearchBase <String>][-SearchScope <ADSearchScope>]
   [-Server <String>][-ShowMemberTimeToLive][<CommonParameters>]
```

for more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroup?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

And also try these examples

```
   Get-ADGroup ''Domain Admins'' -Property member –ShowMemberTimeToLive 
    
   Get-ADGroup -Identity "***" -Property member –ShowMemberTimeToLive ***- Add AD group distinguished name (DN), GUID, security identifier (SID), Security Accounts Manager (SAM) account name, or canonical name along with -Property member –ShowMemberTimeToLive
```

For more reference check with this [link](http://woshub.com/temporary-membership-in-active-directory-groups/)

Answer (score -1):

You have to activate the PAM feature in order to use this switch. Here is a good writeup:
https://richardjgreen.net/active-directory-2016-time-based-group-membership/